# GoldenDict error while loading

Tags: dependencies, shared-library, goldendict

I installed `goldendict`, but when I tried to run it the terminal tells me:

```
goldendict: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Svg.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".
```

I checked that `libqt5svg5` and `libqt5svg5-dev` are both installed. How to solve the problem?
The output of `apt-cache policy goldendict` is

```
goldendict:
Installed: 1.5.0~rc2+git20170908+ds-1
Candidate: 1.5.0~rc2+git20170908+ds-1
Version table:
*** 1.5.0~rc2+git20170908+ds-1 500
    500 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and I don't have Qt-related PPAs.

Comment: How did you install ColorDict? Did you use `sudo apt install goldendict`?

Comment: I used `sudo apt install goldendict` to install goldendict.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy goldendict` to the question). Do you have Qt-related PPAs?