# GParted can't work

Tags: dependencies, gparted, 18.04, libraries

I installed Gparted with `sudo apt install gparted` and `sudo apt install -f`. When I typed `sudo gparted`, it tells me:

```
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
/usr/sbin/gpartedbin: error while loading shared libraries: libglibmm-2.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and it's not the first time that I met such library related problem (see [another question posted by me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036612/goldendict-error-while-loading)).
I found a review in Ubuntu Software telling me that GParted can't run on 18.04, so I consider this a version related problem.
The output for `apt-cache policy gparted libgtkmm-2.4-1v5` is

```
gparted:
Installed: 0.30.0-3ubuntu1
Candidate: 0.30.0-3ubuntu1
Version table:
*** 0.30.0-3ubuntu1 500
    500 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:
Installed: 1:2.24.5-2
Candidate: 1:2.24.5-2
Version table:
*** 1:2.24.5-2 500
    500 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The output for `grep -r -v ^# /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep ppa` is

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/snwh-ubuntu-pulp-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/pulp/ubuntu bionic main
```

The output for `ldd /usr/sbin/gpartedbin | grep not` is

```
libcairomm-1.0.so.1 => not found
libgiomm-2.4.so.1 => not found
libglibmm-2.4.so.1 => not found
libsigc-2.0.so.0 => not found
```

But when I run `sudo apt install libglibmm-2.4-1v5` (also for other missing libraries) it says something like

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglibmm-2.4-1v5 is already the newest version (2.56.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I reinstalled the packages with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libsigc++-2.0-0v5` and executed

```
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairomm-1.0.so.1 | grep not
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1 | grep not
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 | grep not
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigc-2.0.so.0 | grep not
```

GParted can now function well. Thanks for everyone's sincere help.

Comment: Your system seems to be broken.  All these packages install normally on clean 18.04 LTS. Please add output of the `apt-cache policy gparted libgtkmm-2.4-1v5` (source of gparted and libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 packages) and `grep -r -v ^# /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep ppa` (list of your PPAs), `ldd /usr/sbin/gpartedbin | grep not` (missed libraries by gparted) to the question.

Comment: So we have four library packages - try to reinstall them `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libsigc++-2.0-0v5` and then try to find broken libraries with `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairomm-1.0.so.1 | grep not`, `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1 | grep not`,  `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 | grep not`, `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigc-2.0.so.0 | grep not`. Add all outputs to question.

Comment: I posted my last comment as answer, so you can accept it and vote for it.

Comment: any drive you wish to alter using gparted should NOT be currently mounted ... this means you should boot your box using a ubuntu liveCD or  USB ... once booted from liveCD launch its gparted ... it makes little sense to install or execute gparted on your laptop/desktop itself as by definition your drive will be mounted rendering ability of gparted moot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have four libraries:

- *libcairomm-1.0.so.1*
- *libgiomm-2.4.so.1*
- *libglibmm-2.4.so.1*
- *libsigc-2.0.so.0*

Try to reinstall their packages with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 \
libsigc++-2.0-0v5
```

Then check their linkage:

```
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairomm-1.0.so.1 | grep not
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1 | grep not
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 | grep not
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigc-2.0.so.0 | grep not
```